# VARIANT structure deserialization code organization

Tags: c#, generics, com

In my project i work with COM object via `System.Reflection`. COM object returns pointer on structure `VARIANT`, that i cast as `object` and then i cast one as `byte array`. There are many structures that i get from COM object. Since i know about how organize these structure i write static class to deserialize them byte-by-byte according to their structure. Because i have many structures with different fields i have many methods: one method for deserialize one structure. Then i write generics method when i call these method depend on some number of structure. Is this correct code organization?

Class:

```
using SpRReaderSocketServerLib.SpRRecordLib;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SpRReaderSocketServerLib.SpRTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static class for deserialize structures from unmanaged code via BinaryReader and MemoryStream.
    /// 1. SPR_MSG_RECORD_START => MSGRecordStart - ok
    /// 2. SPR_MSG_RECORD_STOP => MSGRecordStop - ok
    /// 3. SPR_MSG_ANI_DETECT => MSGPhoneNumber - ok
    /// 4. SPR_MSG_DIALLED_PHONE => MSGPhoneNumber
    /// 5. SPR_MSG_RING => MSGRing - ok
    /// 6. SPR_MSG_MISSED_PHONE => MSGMissedPhone - ok - for tests
    /// </summary>
    public static class Deserializer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generic method for deserialize messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Struct</typeparam>
        /// <param name="msgId">Message Id</param>
        /// <param name="msgObject">Message as object</param>
        /// <returns>T Struct</returns>
        public static T DeserializeMsg<T>(int msgId, object msgObject) where T : struct
        {
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])msgObject;

            switch (msgId)
            {
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_HEADER:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeHeader(bytes), typeof(T));
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_RING:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeRing(bytes), typeof(T));
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_RECORD_START:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeRecordStart(bytes), typeof(T));
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_RECORD_STOP:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeRecordStop(bytes), typeof(T));
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_ANI_DETECT:
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_DIALLED_PHONE:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializePhoneNumber(bytes), typeof(T));
                case SpRecordLibTypesW.SPR_MSG_MISSED_PHONE:
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeMissedPhone(bytes), typeof(T));
                default:
                    return default(T);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize object with MSGHeader structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message from SpRecord system</param>
        /// <returns>MSGHeader</returns>
        private static MSGHeader DeserializeHeader(byte[] message)
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(message);
            MSGHeader msgHeader = new MSGHeader();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
            {
                msgHeader.dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(); // 4
                msgHeader.dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
                msgHeader.MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()); // + 8
            }

            return msgHeader; // = 16
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize object with MSGRing structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message from SpRecord system</param>
        /// <returns>MSGRing</returns>
        private static MSGRing DeserializeRing(byte[] message)
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(message);
            MSGRing msgRing = new MSGRing();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
            {
                msgRing.mh.dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(); // 4
                msgRing.mh.dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
                msgRing.mh.MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()); // + 8

                msgRing.cbChannelName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgRing.dwRingCount = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
            }

            return msgRing; // 116
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize object with MSGMissedPhone structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message from SpRecord system</param>
        /// <returns>MSGMissedPhone</returns>
        private static MSGMissedPhone DeserializeMissedPhone(byte[] message)
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(message);
            MSGMissedPhone msgMissedPhone = new MSGMissedPhone();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
            {
                msgMissedPhone.mh.dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(); // 4
                msgMissedPhone.mh.dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
                msgMissedPhone.mh.MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()); // + 8

                msgMissedPhone.cbChannelName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgMissedPhone.cbPhoneFrom = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgMissedPhone.cbSubPhoneFrom = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_SUBPHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 24*2
                msgMissedPhone.cbPhoneTo = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgMissedPhone.cbSubPhoneTo = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_SUBPHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 24*2
            }

            return msgMissedPhone; // = 400
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize object with MSGRecordStart structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message from SpRecord system</param>
        /// <returns>MSGRecordStart</returns>
        private static MSGRecordStart DeserializeRecordStart(byte[] message)
        {
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(message);
            MSGRecordStart msgRecordStart = new MSGRecordStart();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
            {
                msgRecordStart.mh.dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(); // 4
                msgRecordStart.mh.dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
                msgRecordStart.mh.MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()); // + 8

                msgRecordStart.cbChannelName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgRecordStart.dwRecordType = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
                msgRecordStart.cbPhoneFrom = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgRecordStart.cbSubPhoneFrom = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_SUBPHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 24*2
                msgRecordStart.cbPhoneTo = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_PHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
                msgRecordStart.cbSubPhoneTo = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_SUBPHONE_NUMBER_CHARS * 2)); // + 24*2
                msgRecordStart.cbFileName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_PATH * 2)); // + 260*2
            }

            return msgRecordStart; // = 924
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that if possible, you shouldn't do this manually. Can you use .Net 4.5.1? It seems to have a [new method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261460) that could help with this.

Comment: I use .NET 4. As to marshalling i have some problem with one, for example all structures are nested and before parse any outer structure i must parse inner structure in order to get type of outer structure. Deserializing via `BinaryReader` good option for me. Everything work fine. I would like to ask about my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int msgId
```

I think it would be better if this was an `enum`. That way, it's clear what values are acceptable for this parameter.

```
object msgObject
```

Since this method only accepts `byte[]`, I think that should be the parameter. It will then be a responsibility of the caller to do the casting.

```
(T)Convert.ChangeType(DeserializeHeader(bytes), typeof(T))
```

Unless you actually need to perform some conversions here, what you can do is to write just `(T)(object)DeserializeHeader(bytes)`. This works around the fact that the compiler doesn't know what code to generate for `(T)DeserializeHeader(bytes)`, because it could be a custom conversion.

```
default:
    return default(T);
```

I think that this means that the `msgId` parameter is invalid, so this should be an error and you should throw an exception here.

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream(message);
```

This variable is very simple and used only in one place, you could inline it: `new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(message))`.

```
msgRing.cbChannelName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2));
```

Why is this a `char[]`? Using `string` would be more natural. To do that, just use `GetString()` instead of `GetChars()`. Though that seems to result in `string` that contains lots of null chars at the end. To fix that, you could use `.TrimEnd('\0')`.

```
msgRing.mh.dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(); // 4
msgRing.mh.dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
msgRing.mh.MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()); // + 8

msgRing.cbChannelName = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2)); // + 48*2
msgRing.dwRingCount = br.ReadInt32(); // + 4
```

You could use object initializer here, something like:

```
return new MSGRing
{
    mh =
    {
        dwMsgSize = br.ReadInt32(), // 4
        dwMsg = br.ReadInt32(), // +4
        MsgTime = DateTime.FromOADate(br.ReadDouble()) // +8
    },
    cbChannelName =
        Encoding.Unicode.GetString(
            br.ReadBytes(
                SpRRecordLib.SpRecordLibTypesW.MAX_CHANNEL_NAME_CHARS * 2)), // + 48*2
    dwRingCount = br.ReadInt32() // + 4
}; // 116
```

Comment: Thank you, svick. I will take into account all of your arguments and fix your code!